# CSS: problems with a floating element in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, css-float

i have this [page](http://tirengarfio.com/miembros).

```
login: miguel@mail.com
pass: m
```

As you can see in FF the filter is on the right of the list, but in IE6 not..

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code does not validate. This would be my first step in getting it to work in Internet Explorer 6. http://validator.w3.org/.

If this does not fix it, I would check up on IE6's layout bugs. See http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html.

If you still haven't found a solution then try with the simplest page, and make that one work in IE6. Then slowly add all the elements on your page, so that you can identify what is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO getting it to look right in IE6 isn't worth the trouble, as you can see (http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp) only 7.1% percent of people are using IE6 now. Was there any specific reason that you have to get it right in IE6? (ie the company you are with has 600 PCs with IE6 on)